# expressjs ldap authentication showing basic auth pop up form

Tags: node.js, express, ldap, openldap

I'm a newbie to expressjs and ldap.

Need your help with getting my way through the code flow.

I need to authenticate user credentials against ldap server.
I'm using this ldap library https://github.com/vesse/node-ldapauth-fork for making it work.

I get the pop-up form on my broswer that asks for my basic auth credentials after I have submitted the login credentials with the login form(loginCtrl.js). 
When i enter the credentials into the popup,  the backends sees them as "undefined"

[image]
My question is why is the basic auth form popping up, if I'm already sending teh credentials via loginCtrl.js

This is my front end code that calls the REST api 
    login.html

```js
app.controller("loginCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$location","$document", "$uibModal", "$filter", "$q", function($scope, $http, $location, $document, $uibModal, $filter, $q) {

 $scope.keepLoggedIn = false;


 $scope.login = function() {
  var body = {};
  body["username"] =  $scope.username;
  body["password"] = $scope.password;

  var auth = window.btoa($scope.username+":"+$scope.password);
  console.log(auth);
 /* $http.post('/login', JSON.stringify(credentials)).then(function(success){
   console.log("success");
  }, function(error){
   console.error("error");
  });*/
  var results = [];
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Authorization': "Basic " + auth},
    url: '/login',
    data: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
  .then(function (success) {
    console.log(success);
    results.push(success);
  }, function (error) {
    results.push(error.data);
  });

 }


}]);
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <form ng-submit="login()">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" id="username" name="username">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" id="password" name="password">
  <div id="lower">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="keepLoggedIn"><label for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </div><!--/ lower-->
 </form>
</div>
```

This is the expressjs server code that uses ldapauth to authenticate against ldap

```
var express = require('express');
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var LdapAuth = require('ldapauth-fork');
var app = express();

var ldap = new LdapAuth({
  url: 'ldap://ldapserver.net:389',
  bindDN: 'uid=root,ou=sample,dc=dept,dc=net',
  bindCredentials: 'secret',
  searchBase: 'ou=sample,dc=dept,dc=net',
  searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})',
  reconnect: true
});

ldap.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('LdapAuth: ', err);
});

var rejectBasicAuth = function(res) {

  res.statusCode = 401;
  res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Example"');
  res.end('Access denied');

}
var basicAuthMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {

  ldap.authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    console.log("callback:"+user);
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return rejectBasicAuth(res);
    }
    console.log("success");
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
app.post('/login',basicAuthMiddleware, function(req,res){
    res.send({"status":"ok"});
});
app.listen(2500, function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + 2500 + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```